# Xamarin Android application closed unexpectedly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

i'm tried to create android application using xamarin studio. iam install xamarin studio and create a new android application. the application successfully run on emulator. but after installing apk in my android phone, when open application i got the message "Unfortunately Application has stopped" . project target version is 4.03.  emulator android version is 4.03 and my phone os version also 4.03.  what is the actual problem.  iam a buginner in xamarin studio.  any idea??

this is the device log

```
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  Process:com.gadgeon.helloworld, PID: 22866
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):   java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to get provider   mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_15 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5002)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_15 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:38)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  ... 11 more
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866): Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Xamarin.Android.Platform
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:281)
09-01 19:12:46.654: E/AndroidRuntime(22866):  at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:32)
```

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Xamarin Studio? What Android SDK version are you targeting, v19?

Comment: iam using xamarin studio 5.9.5(build 10) latest. and Target Android SDK version is Android 4.0.3 (v 15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved.

Cannot take an .apk file created in debug mode.

1. Build project using Release mode.
2. select Build > Archive for Publishing

This will produce a final apk file. we can install and use this apk file without any problems.

Read more about here: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development

Answer (score 1):

Edit your .csproj,

Change:

```
<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
```

To:

```
<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>False</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
```

Then clean, rebuild and reinstall the apk

Comment: in .csproj file <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk> is allready "false" state